# Firefox use system DNS

Tags: firefox, security, dns

I am trying to get Firefox to use my systems dns and ultimately my router's dns which is redirecting all DNS queries to the Quad9 servers. It works fine for Chrome, Vivaldi and Edge however Firefox still can open [isitblocked.org](http://isitblocked.org) which is the reference address recommended by Quad9 for testing.

Any pointers?

Comment: Have you restarted Firefox since the change? It keeps a DNS cache that should normally get cleared when you restart it. If not, there are add-ons which can clear this cache.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/13063496/4464570

Comment: Yeah, tried changing the entries in about:config as well as restarting firefox. In addition i cleared all website data through the interface. I couldn't find an addon compatible with Firefox Quantum (57). As expected nslookup on bash fails.